# One-to-One mapping issue in EF Code First

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Consider this scenario:

```
public class House
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person2 { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public House House { get; set; }
}

// Relationships
this.HasOptional(t => t.Person1)
    .WithRequired(t => t.House);
this.HasOptional(t => t.Person2)
    .WithRequired(t => t.House);
```

When I try to insert an instance of House a MetaDataException is thrown:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  (36,6) : error 0040: Type
>   House_Person1 is not defined in namespace Company.Models (Alias=Self).

After a little more hacking, figured that this works:

```
// Relationships
this.HasOptional(t => t.Person1)
    .WithRequired();
this.HasOptional(t => t.Person2)
    .WithRequired();
```

But then I won't have the Person.House property populated by EF. Can I emulate this behavior (shown below)?

```
    public virtual Person Person1
    {
        get
        {
            return _person1;
        }
        set
        {
            _person1 = value;
            _person1.Haushalt = this;
        }
    }

    public virtual Person Person2
    {
        get
        {
            return _person2;
        }
        set
        {
            _person2 = value;
            _person2.Haushalt = this;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the same navigation property (`Person.House`) in two different relationships (`House_Person1` and `House_Person2`).

An additional limitation is that EF only supports [shared primary key associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx) as true one-to-one relationships. It means that a related `House` and `Person` must have the same primary key value. But from that follows that `House.Person1` and `House.Person2` would need to have the same PK value as the `House`. In other words: `Person1` and `Person2` can never be different persons.

I would suggest that you map your relationship as a one-to-many relationship and ensure in your application's business logic that a `House` must not have more than two `Person`s. (Because your current mapping allows that `Person1` and `Person2` are optional, zero or only one person would be allowed):

```
public class House
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public House House { get; set; }
}

this.HasMany(t => t.People)
    .WithRequired(t => t.House);
```

**Edit**

If you want to keep the two `Person` navigation properties in `House` you can only map this as two one-to-many relationships (even if this relation in wrong from business viewpoint) without having a navigation property in `Person` (like shown [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx)):

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.Person1)
    .WithMany();
this.HasOptional(t => t.Person2)
    .WithMany();
```

You can use the `House` property in `Person` as you did in your last code snippet, but you need to exclude it from the model:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .Ignore(t => t.House);
```

`Person.House` isn't a navigation property anymore you can't load it (with eager or lazy loading) when you load a `Person` entity from the database.

Comment: I do want to keep Person1 and Person2. Anything else you can think of? I was thinking in terms of not having the navigation property Person.House. Refer edited question.

Comment: @Trainee4Life: See my Edit. As said it doesn't make sense to map the two `Person` properties with one-to-one mapping because they will share the primary key with `House`, so that the two `Person`s cannot be different.